# Multi Select value each loop using $(this)

Tags: jquery, this

I have 2 multiselect fields. I want run each loop when user select value from which ever is selected. I am trying the following code this is giving me error.

```
 $('[name=filterPartLang], [name=partViewLang_Edit]').change(function(){   
        partLang = [];              
        $($(this)+':selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
            partLang[i] = $(selected).text();                               
        });                                                             
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('[name=filterPartLang], [name=partViewLang_Edit]').change(function () {
    var partLang = [];
    $(this).find(':selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        partLang[i] = $(selected).text();
    });
});
```

or using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
$('[name=filterPartLang], [name=partViewLang_Edit]').change(function () {
    var partLang = $(this).find(':selected').map(function (i, selected) {
        return $(selected).text();
    }).get();
});
```

In your selector `$($(this)+':selected')` will produce `[object Object]:selected` because `$(this)` returns an object whose `toString()` will return `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for the descendants and use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) over the retrieved collection to group the text into an array,

```
partLang = $(this).find(':selected').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

---

Full code,

```
$('[name=filterPartLang],[name=partViewLang_Edit]').change(function(){
 partLang = $(this).find(':selected').map(function(){
      return $(this).text();
 }).get();
});
```